# Is it possible to do something after Jquery pulsate finishes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation

I am checking in a form that with onfocusout function that the value of input already exist in database.If exists i am pulsating the input for 5 times as below;

```
  cell.pulsate({ //cell is my selector 
         color: "#bf1c56",
         repeat: 5,
  });
```

but the problem is that i am not fetching the pulsate finish . I want to add css to input after pulsate works 5 times. I cannot find complete or finish option of pulsate.Is there any usage as i want ?

Comment: which plugin you are using for this `pulsate`?

Comment: If you're using https://github.com/Kilian/jQuery.pulsate, you can just bind a timeout call for (repeat * speed). In the example above that would be a 5000 ms timeout

Comment: yes, sorry i did not mention the plugin in question. I use this plugin

Comment: To specify the question, I want to keep the box-shadow css the animation after pulsating finishes

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`toggle`](https://api.jqueryui.com/toggle/) method

```
cell.toggle( "pulsate", {
    color: "#bf1c56",
    repeat: 5
}, function() {
    alert("I will be called when pulsate is finished");
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help but the options of plugin not working now ?

Comment: ok... toggle() method exists both in jquery and jquery-ui. My solution works with jquery-ui version. Not sure you can do it in plain jquery. Still investigating...